# ASP.NET MVC 3: Using Enumerable extension methods in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, separation-of-concerns

Given the following Razor Partial View and understanding that Product is an NHibernate mapped object so the calls to IEnumerable here will fire database queries (when not cached).

Is this bad practice? Should I be providing a flatter view of my data for this view so that I can make these calls in my controller/business logic?

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Models.Product>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Total Orders</th>
        <th>Fulfilled</th>
        <th>Returned</th>
        <th>In stock</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var product in Model) { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(product .Name, "Detail", "Product", new { id = product.Id }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @product.Orders.Count
            </td>
            <td>
                @product.Orders.Where(x=>x.Fulfilled).Count()
            </td>
            <td>
                @product.Orders.Where(x=>x.Returned).Count()
            </td>
            <td>
                @(product.Stock.Count - product.Orders.Count)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this bad practice?

**Yes.**. In fact it's breaking the MVC pattern - the View's should not call back through the model, only receive in order to do it's sole job: rendering HTML.

If you need additional information than just the one entity, populate a **ViewModel** with all the information you need, then pass that to your View.

Also, don't loop through the `IEnumerable` in the model, use a *Display Template:*

`@Html.DisplayForModel()`

The advantage of this is no explicit loop, taking advantage of MVC conventions, and adhering to model hierachy when model binding.

Comment: It seems like an easy pragmatic way to do things, but I kind of knew it was wrong from an MVC standpoint.

Comment: yup. whenever you start writing code in your Views, unless it's `@Html.<somehelper>`, alarm bells should go off and you should refactor your view/controller to simplify things. Put any logic in your ViewModels or Controller.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using a foreach to loop through your IEnumberable from your model, as long as it is only for rendering HTML rendering logic. The helpers are great, but not using them doesnt break the MVC pattern. (@product.Orders.Where(x=>x.Fulfilled).Count() does, however)

Comment: @WeekendWarrior - your right, there is nothing wrong with using a foreach to loop through your model, as long as it's only for rendering HTML - **but in this case**, it's calling through to the model again, which is what breaks the pattern. And even basic foreach loops, if you can avoid them, you should. Why write code in Views when it can be avoided?